# loading image onto dynamic button created in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[EDIT: I've now created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fraserYT/fy4ngq4d/4/) of the problem]

I've been trying to adapt [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeGooeyEffects/menu.html) gooey effects button, by Lucas Bebber, for my own project. Unlike the static buttons in the example, I need to change the function of the button depending on the context, so construct them in jQuery, but can't get the icons to load onto the buttons in any browser other than Chrome.

The function I think the problem lies within is this one, which is at line 157 of the jsFiddle.

```
function buttonMapper() {
    var clickNameF = window[futurePage + '_click'];
    var clickNameB = window[oldPage + '_click'];

    $backIcon = $('<i/>', {
        'class': 'backGlass',
            'id': 'backIhold',
            'width': '70%'
    });
    $fwdIcon = $('<i/>', {
        'class': 'fwdGlass',
            'id': 'fwdIhold',
            'width': '70%',
    });
    $backButton = $('<button/>', {
        type: 'button',
            'class': 'menu-item-button',
            'id': oldPage + '_btn',
            'title': pageLabels[prevPage],
        click: function () {
            clickNameB();
        }
    });
    $forwardButton = $('<button/>', {
        type: 'button',
            'class': 'menu-item-button',
            'id': futurePage + '_btn',
            'title': pageLabels[nextPage],
        click: function () {
            clickNameF();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: An example in a fiddle would really help us help you debug. Where is this function `window[futurePage + '_click']` defined?

Comment: A fair point. I started putting a fiddle together but with so many separate libs and functions that are all interrelated, I wasn't sure anyone would read on, so tried to strip out everything I think is unrelated. I'll go back to the fiddle now and try to get a minimalistic working version for now.

Comment: But in answer to your question, there is a separate function for each page: page1_click, page2_click etc. Each one just sets a number of variables required to construct the page (what this, next and previous page numbers are and whether back or forward buttons are required on the page, then fires another function which contains the specific page content

Comment: The buttons are actually being created and appended as expected. It's the inline styles that are not being applied on FF etc. Looks like something to do with the external libraries that are in use.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. At least I know where to focus my attentions